# How to properly handle a TextField binding and keep the nodereference separate from the Task

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

My question applies to a broader range of nodes than just TextField, but my example includes only this specific type of node.

My application changes the content of a TextField which displays the name of a country based on the selection of a city made from a ChoiceBox:

[image: My application changes the content of a TextField which displays the name of a country based on the selection of a city made from a ChoiceBox]

I accomplish this by setting the text of `countryTextField` in a `Task<Void>` using the `onAction` event handler for the choice box:

```
@FXML
public void handleCityChoice() {
    new Thread(new CityChoiceTask(cityChoiceBox.getValue())).start();
}

class CityChoiceTask extends Task<Void> {
    String selection;
    CityChoiceTask(String selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> countryTextField.setText(Datasource.getInstance().
                getCountryNameByCityName(selection)));
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works just fine, but really what I want to do is completely separate the node referencing from the `Task` code because it is a best practice to do so (I'm just a student, so correct me if I'm wrong about this, but it's what I was taught). I tried  the following, but keep throwing a `NullPointerException`, I believe it is because the task thread doesn't complete before the bind is executed:

```
@FXML
public void handleCityChoice() {
    Task task = new CityChoiceTask(cityChoiceBox.getValue());
    new Thread(task).start();
    countryTextField.textProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
}

class CityChoiceTask extends Task<SimpleStringProperty> {
    String selection;
    CityChoiceTask(String selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }
    @Override
    public SimpleStringProperty call() {
        String result = Datasource.getInstance().getCountryNameByCityName(selection));
        return new SimpleStringProperty(result);
    }
}
```

Also, `System.out.println(task.valueProperty());`

prints:

> ObjectProperty [bean: controller.AddCustomer$CityChoiceTask@8b85d08,
>   name: value, value: null]

Is the thread not executing in time indeed why it's throwing a `NullPointerException`, and is there a way to fix it?

On a side note, this sort of bind works just fine when using TableView.
For instance, using a Task that returns a ValueProperty of `FXCollections.observableArrayList`, something like `myTableView.itemsProperty().bind(task);` works just fine, regardless of when the thread finished execution.

Comment: Try adding the type parameter to `Task` in your second code snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the proper return type as type parameter to the `Task`. Since you want to assign a ***String***Property, you need to use `String`. (Your compiler would have complained about this error, if you didn't use the raw type.)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField text = new TextField();

    Button btn = new Button("Run");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {

            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return "Hello World";
            }

        };
        text.textProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
        new Thread(task).start();
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(btn, text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

You could also post intermediate updates using `updateValue` method.

---

Also note that your first snippet does not really do any work on the non-application thread. The task is only used to schedule the code for retrieving the information later on the application thread. Also using `Task` for this purpose is unnecessary. A simple `Runnable` would suffice:

```
final String selection = cityChoiceBox.getValue();
new Thread(() ->  {
    // do this on this thread, not on the JavaFX application thread
    final String result = Datasource.getInstance().getCountryNameByCityName(selection);

    Platform.runLater(() -> countryTextField.setText(result));
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change type of your task to `String` and call `updateValue()` from the `call()` method of your task:

```
class CityChoiceTask extends Task<String> {

    private final String selection;

    CityChoiceTask(String selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        String result = Datasource.getInstance().getCountryNameByCityName(selection);
        updateValue(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And in your `handleCityChoice()` method you should bind `countryTextField.textProperty()` prior to starting thread as it can finish execution before the next line of code (creating the binding) will be executed, making your `countryText` field be never updated:

```
@FXML
public void handleCityChoice() {
    CityChoiceTask task = new CityChoiceTask(cityChoiceBox.getValue());
    countryTextField.textProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();

}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, this was the problem. I needed to change the `Task<SimpleStringProperty>` to `Task<String>`. I also used the raw type Task for the reference which was a mistake because it didn't throw a compiler error.  And thank you for the tip about `udpateValue()` and the binding of `countryTextField.textProperty()` before starting the thread; I didn't know you needed to bind the value before the thread finished executing. I had to give the answer to fabian because he posted first, but yours was the answer as well.